# $\|u_m(0)\|_{H^2(U)}^2 \leq C\|\Delta u_m(0)\|_{L^2(U)}^2$

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

$\def\d{\mathop{d}\!}$
Source: Evans' PDE book, section 7.1, below equation (51)

Question: how to derive $\|u_m(0)\|_{H^2(U)}^2 \leq C\|\Delta u_m(0)\|_{L^2(U)}^2$?

Here is my attempts:

By definition
$$ \|u_m(0)\|_{H^2}^2 = \|u_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2 + \|Du_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2 +
    \int_U |D^2 u_m(0)|^2 \d x.$$
Since $u_m(0)=0$ on $\partial U$, by Poincaré's inequality we have
$$ \|u_m(0)\|_{L^2} \leq C\|Du_m(0)\|_{L^2}. $$
Using Green's theorem and the above inequality, we find
\begin{align*}
    \|Du_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2
    & = \int_U Du_m(0)\cdot Du_m(0) \d x \\
    & = \int_U \operatorname{div} (u_m(0)Du_m(0)) - u_m(0)\Delta u_m(0) \d x \\
    & \leq \|u_m(0)\|_{L^2} \|\Delta u_m(0)\|_{L^2} \\
    & \leq C\|Du_m(0)\|_{L^2} \|\Delta u_m(0)\|_{L^2}.
  \end{align*}
Hence $\|Du_m(0)\|_{L^2}\leq C\|\Delta u_m(0)\|_{L^2}$ and
$$ \|u_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2 + \|Du_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2 \leq C\|\Delta u_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2. $$
Now we only need to estimate the last term
$\int_U |D^2 u_m(0)|^2 d x$. Fix $(i,j)$ and integrate by parts to get
\begin{align*}
    & \int_U u_m(0)_{x_ix_j} u_m(0)_{x_ix_j} \d x \\
    ={} & \int_{\partial U} u_m(0)_{x_ix_j}u_m(0)_{x_i}\nu_j \d S
          - \int_{\partial U} u_m(0)_{x_i} u_m(0)_{x_jx_j} \nu_i \d S
          + \int_U u_m(0)_{x_ix_i} u_m(0)_{x_jx_j} \d x.
  \end{align*}
Therefore (using $\Delta u_m(0) = 0$ on $\partial U$)
\begin{align*}
    \int_U |D^2 u_m(0)|^2 \d x
    & = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \int_U u_m(0)_{x_ix_j} u_m(0)_{x_ix_j} \d x \\
    & = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \int_{\partial U} u_m(0)_{x_ix_j}u_m(0)_{x_i}\nu_j \d S 
        + \|\Delta u_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2.
  \end{align*}
Now the question is reduced to estimate the boundary integration
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \int_U u_m(0)_{x_ix_j} u_m(0)_{x_ix_j} \d x.$$

However, I'm stuck with this last step.

Comment: Try using Green's theorem on $\| Du\|_{L^2}^2$, this should give you a more usable expression.

Comment: @Willow Wisp Using Green's theorem we can get $\|Du_m(0)\|_{L^2}^2 = -\int_U u_m(0)\Delta u_m(0)dx$, then how to proceed?

Comment: Then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality will get you something in terms of $\|\Delta u\|_{L^2}$ and $\|u\|_{L^2}$. Reusing the Poincaré inequality should then get you almost all the way there.

Comment: Fine thank you@WillowWisp

Comment: You have to use $H^2$-regularity theory for elliptic equations. The estimate is only true under suitable assumptions on $U$.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more?@daw